# Are the elements of a value chain called "stages," "links," "steps," or something else?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I would like to know what is the most appropriate and common word to name the different elements of a value chain. Is it:

- the **stages** of the value chain
- the **links** of the value chain
- the **steps** of the value chain
- any other word?

Answer (score 2):

Googling "value chain" leads to [this article](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/v/valuechain.asp), which starts with this:

> A value chain is a series of consecutive **steps** that go into the creation of a finished product, from its initial design to its arrival at a customer's door.

So, I would use *steps*.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that there are also other articles using "stages" and "links" as well. It's hard to tell if there is a preferred word or a subtle difference in meaning between the 3 words. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: @wangli I see. I would still use *steps*. I don't think there's enough difference between them to make a difference. An actual chain has links, but here the chain is abstract. We can say links in a chain of events, but we're really talking about steps in a series of events. Stages has more the feeling of accomplishments. Steps is simple and describes the points in the series.

Comment: My problem with "steps" is that it maybe implies (I am not sure) that the different stages are consecutive (which the idea of "chain" in the "value chain" concept also may imply). However, in practice, a value chain includes many parallel processes (imagine a tree with many roots).

Comment: @wangli That is a thoughtful distinction, and thank you for clarifying that the processes involved can be parallel. Given that, the metaphor of a chain makes some sense. I would say that both "steps" and "stages" give the idea of one after the other, while "links" does not. While I think that anyone knowing what a value chain is would understand what you have just explained, perhaps "links" is the term that least implies some sort of sequence. Maybe that's why it's one of the terms in use.

Comment: Chains have links, so value chain also implies that and the article writers chose to call those steps, which makes total sense.